# How can i get the key of an element in stack-layout in d3?

Tags: d3.js

I want to add a toolkit that show the type of the disaster, which is the key of the stack datum, how can i get it?

The format of `.csv` file is like this: (Forgive me can not take pictures)

```
AllNaturalDisasters,Drought,Earthquake,ExtremeTemperature,ExtremeWeather,Flood,Impact,Landslide,MassMovementDry,VolcanicActivity,Wildfire,Year
5,2,null,null,1,1,null,null,null,1,null,1900
2,null,2,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,1901
```

Here I create a stack

```
var stack = d3.stack()
  .keys(["Drought", "Earthquake", "ExtremeTemperature", "ExtremeWeather", "Flood", "Impact", "Landslide", "MassMovementDry", "VolcanicActivity", "Wildfire"]);
```

and then I pass it my data:`var series = stack(dataset);`. `dataset` is the all data from the `csv` file. Then I create a chart using stack-layout, like this:

```
var groups = svg.selectAll("g")
    .data(series)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .style("fill", function(d, i) {
        return colors(i);
    });

var rects = groups.selectAll("rect")
    .data(function(d) { return d; })
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("x", function(d, i) {
        return xScale(i);
    })
    .attr("y", function(d) {
        return yScale(d[1]);
    })
    .attr("height", function(d) {
        return yScale(d[0]) - yScale(d[1]);
    })
    .attr("width", xScale.bandwidth())
    .append("title")
    .text(function (d) {
        return d.data.Year;
    });
```

The problem is right here:

```
.append("title")
    .text(function (d) {
        return d.data.Year;
    });
```

I want to add a toolkit to show the type of the disaster, which is the key of this datum in `series` , how can I get it instead of the year?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each rectangle contains information on the column (year of disaster), but each `g` has information on the "row" (type of disaster).

The stack produces a nested array, the parent level (which we use to create the `g` elements) contains the key, or type of disaster

The child level represents the columns, which contains the year.

The grandchild level just contains individual rectangles.

So, we can get a key by selecting the parent `g`:

```
.append("title")
  .text(function() {
     var rect = this.parentNode; // the rectangle, parent of the title
     var g = rect.parentNode;    // the g, parent of the rect.
     return d3.select(g).datum().key; // now we get the key.
  })
```

Of course this could be simplified a bit, but I broke it out to comment it better.

This allows for more flexible sorting - rather than relying on fixed indexes.

Here it is using your data:

```js
var csv = d3.csvParse(d3.select("pre").text());


var stack = d3.stack().keys(["Drought", "Earthquake", "ExtremeTemperature", "ExtremeWeather", "Flood", "Impact", "Landslide", "MassMovementDry", "VolcanicActivity", "Wildfire"]);

var series = stack(csv);

var colors = d3.scaleOrdinal()
  .range(d3.schemeCategory10);
  
var xScale = d3.scaleBand()
  .domain([0,1])
  .range([0,300])
  
var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0,6])
  .range([200,0]);

var svg = d3.select("svg");
  
var groups = svg.selectAll("g")
  .data(series)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .style("fill", function(d, i) {
     return colors(i);
   });

var rects = groups.selectAll("rect")
  .data(function(d) { return d; })
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("x", function(d, i) {
    return xScale(i);
  })
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return yScale(d[1]);
  })
  .attr("height", function(d) {
     return yScale(d[0]) - yScale(d[1]);
  })
  .attr("width", xScale.bandwidth())
  .append("title")
  .text(function (d) {
      var rect = this.parentNode;
      var g = rect.parentNode;
      return d3.select(g).datum().key;
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>

<svg width="400" height="300"></svg>


<pre>AllNaturalDisasters,Drought,Earthquake,ExtremeTemperature,ExtremeWeather,Flood,Impact,Landslide,MassMovementDry,VolcanicActivity,Wildfire,Year
5,2,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1900
2,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1901</pre>
```

Comment: Cool!! Thanks a lot! Your answer can solve my problem perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have fixed this problem by a very 'low' method. I have created a simple function:

```
function getKeys(d) {
            return series[parseInt(groups.selectAll("rect").data().indexOf(d) / series[0].length)].key;
        }
```

Well, it so simple and crude, and I still want to know a more efficient method!!!